# ActionView::Template::Error - No route matches action in button_to \ link_to calling controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, redmine

I'm trying to create a view with a button calling a controller action for a Redmine Plugin (unfortunately, I'm quite new at Rails). I'd need to create a method for my controller (here A Controller) so i can update some Active Records.

I created a controller:

redmine_a_controller.rb

```
class RedmineAController < ApplicationController

  def prova(input)
    puts input
    return input
  end

  def p
    puts 'vuoto'
    returns 'vuoto'
  end

end
```

The actions work correctly when called from the console. Unfortunately, when called from my view _a.html.erb:

```
  <%= 
      button_to l(:imp_update), {
        :controller => 'RedmineAController',
        :action => 'p',
        method: :post
      }
  %>
```

It returns this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"p", :controller=>"RedmineAController", :id=>"prova", :method=>:post, :tab=>"important_users"}):
```

I tried by calling the action on a new instance:

```
  <%= 
      button_to l(:imp_update), {
        :action => RedmineImportantUsersController.new.prova(1),
        method: :post
      }
  %>
```

but it looks for the action in the Projects controller

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"1", :controller=>"projects", :id=>"prova", :method=>:post}):
```

How can I make button_to call the correct `prova` method in the `RedmineAController` controller?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add routes in **routes.rb** file

```
resources :redmine_as do 
  collections do 
    post :a
  end
end
```

After that, Please fine the Routes url by typing on terminal below command

```
rake routes | grep p
```

Set the url in Link or button

```
link_to "Your Link Name", p_redmine_as_path
```

**p_redmines_path** it will be return by that "rake routes 
 | grep p" command.

Answer (score 0):

As Ketan indicated, I was missing a route!

I put in my routes.rb:

```
resources :important_user do 
    collection do 
      post :u_update
    end
  end
```

and in my controller:

```
  def u_update
      puts params[:p_id] 
      puts "update!"
  end
```